# How to convert a string value in dataframe to float

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a csv file and I have to clean data.The problem is that I can fill the empty values by df.fillna() but there are some continious numbers in string which needs to be converted to float or int for further calculations.
I tried couple of methods but cannot find a solution.
Kindly help  as I am new in data science field and maybe have made some mistake asking the question.

This column has an string value : `df['hum'][316] = '64.70'`

```
type(df['hum'][316]) = str
```

I stored the string value to a variable and then used float(value) but it gives an error.

```
value = df['hum'][316]
>>>' "64.70"'
type(value)
>>> str
float(value)
>>>ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' "64.70"'


ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' "64.70"'
```

Comment: It looks like your string as a leading space, is this correct? try `df['hum'].str.lstrip().astype(float)`

Comment: It looks like you have embedded double quotes, try `df['hum'].str.strip().str.replace('"','').astype(float)`

Comment: OK, so now we have multiple people who cannot reproduce your error, at this stage you need to post your actual data and code in order for others to assist you and not waste anymore time

Comment: Sorry but no, I don't do chats. Post a link to your data or post enough data as text and your code that reproduces this issue. Consider it from our point of view, if we can't reproduce your error and you continually tell us, it still doesn't work how is this productive?

Answer (score 0):

seems the problems is the `"` inside the string, remove it by using a regular expression

```
import re
value = df['hum'][316]
value=re.sub('"','',value)
float(value)
```

instead of float possible to check also `astype` for cast operations applying on the whole  df or series (column)

if you want to change the whole column of df to a float try:

```
df['hum'] = df['hum'].str.replace('"', '')
df['hum']=df['hum'].astype('float')
```

regards giulio

Comment: to modify the dataframe try (maybe there are best options):  df['hum'][316]=float(re.sub('"','',df['hum'][316]))

Answer (score 0):

df['hum'][316] = float(df['hum'][316])